# jquery. my ajax registration form has an error message; .JSON.parse: unexpected character error

Tags: jquery

i am new to jquery and still very confused by its concepts.

i have a php MySQL script for registartion of new members. i have just introduced an AJAX script that will enable me to uploaded the completed form without reloading the page.

i have enclosed my code below. the problem is that i keep getting this message:

```
**> There was an SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character error due
> to a parsererror condition.**
```

Can someone please tell me what it means, i have looked over my code and i cant seem to find anything wrong with it.

```
    $('form #response').hide();

$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    // prevent forms default action until
    // error check has been performed
    e.preventDefault();

    // grab form field values
    var valid = '';
    var required = ' is required.';
    var name = $('form #name').val();
    var email = $('form #email').val();
    var cat = $('form #cat option:selected').val();
    var location = $('form #country_loc option:selected').val();
    var honeypot = $('form #honeypot').val();
    var humancheck = $('form #humancheck').val();

    // perform error checking
    if (name = '' || name.length <= 2   ||  name == 'name*'   ) {
        valid = '<p>Your name' + required +'</p>';  
    }

    if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
        valid += '<p>Your email' + required   +'</p>';                                                
    }

    if (cat = '' || cat.length < 1) {
        valid += '<p>Please tell us whether you are;  seeking work or  looking for a careworker' + required + '</p>';   
    }


if (location = '' || location.length < 1) {
        valid += '<p>Please tell us your current location' + required + '</p>'; 
    }



    if (honeypot != 'http://') {
        valid += '<p>Spambots are not allowed.</p>';    
    }

    if (humancheck != '') {
        valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>'; 
    }

    // let the user know if there are erros with the form
    if (valid != '') {

        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
            .html('<strong>Please correct the errors below.</strong>' +valid).fadeIn('fast')            

        .html('<strong>the category is '+ cat     +  '.</strong>' +valid).fadeIn('fast');






    }
    // let the user know something is happening behind the scenes
    // serialize the form data and send to our ajax function
    else {

        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Processing...').fadeIn('fast');                                      

        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        submitForm(formData);           
    }           

});


//END THE FUNCTION FOR THE SUBMISSION OF REGISTATION FORM TO THE DATABASE VIA AJAX 



// make our ajax request to the server
function submitForm(formData) {

    $.ajax({    
        type: 'POST',

        url: 'cms/index.php?view=joint_reg',        
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 7000,
        success: function(data) {           

            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                        .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast'); 

            if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {

                setTimeout("$('form #response').fadeOut('fast')", 5000);
            }

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<p>There was an<strong> ' + errorThrown +
                              '</strong> error due to a<strong> ' + textStatus +
                              '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');           
        },              
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {            

            $('form')[0].reset();
        }
    }); 
};
```

thank you for your help everyone.  i love jquery and really want to learn.

Comment: That would suggest there's a problem with the response from the server and that it's not actually returning valid JSON.

Comment: Can you provide the JSON that throws the error?

Comment: $.ajax({    
        type: 'POST',

        url: 'cms/index.php?view=joint_reg',        
         data: "{'example': '"+formData+"'}", just edit your data line i guess the problem is from it

Answer (score 0):

$('form').serialize() return a string (Ex: formData is "name=abc&email=abc@bla.com... ")

data option must be object so it will throw exception

You can try

```
$.ajax({    

     url: 'cms/index.php?view=joint_reg&' + formData,      

});
```

Hope it help :)

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: hi. thanks Hai Lu for explaining why the system through an exception. i note the comment that i should attach the formData to the URL. however. i am sending the data by POST and not as a GET. so, is it still possible to add the data to teh URL . also, i did try to add the formData to the URL but it still threw an exception. is there a way to make the  0 down vote accept
 

$('form').serialize() into an object